# SQL Azure Inter Geographic Data-Center Transfer Pricing

Tags: sql, windows, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

We all know that the data transfer from Azure to SQL Azure is free, but data access from non Azure Data-Center is charged(per Gigabytes).

Is the Data transfer from Inter Azure Data Centers also free...?

**i.e. : Azure from EUROPE Data-Center and SQL Azure from Asia Data-Center : Is this also free?**

---

References :

- [SQL Azure Pricing Explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2011/03/11/10140075.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are not free.

Following the [Microsoft explanation](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/):

*Data transfers measured in GB (transmissions to and from the Windows Azure datacenter): Data transfers are charged based on the total amount of data going in and out of the Azure services via the internet in a given billing period. **Data transfers within a sub region are free.***

Answer (score 2):

It is not free.

Our company has servers and databases in both US North and US South datacenters and we are charged for any SQL Azure bandwidth sent between the two.